# Spring Security always returns 401 when logging in

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to Java and Spring.

Every-time I send a post request to my server with the details of a user that already exists in my database I always get a 401 unauthorised response and I am not sure why.

**Security Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

@Autowired
AuthUserService authUserService;


@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());

    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/login").authenticated()
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    return http.build();
}

protected void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.userDetailsService(authUserService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using user credential from database to login then you have to use `DaoAuthenticationProvider` then only Spring Security get to know it have to match your entered credentials with database credential for login.

Then for that you have to use `UserDetailsService` interface to load the user from database and then Spring Security will match the credential and give the access.

Mention below code in your `SecurityConfiguration` class.

```java
@Resource
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
}
```

Then you have to create `UserDetailServiceImpl` class to implements `UserDetailService` interface.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user1 = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if (user1 == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        UserDetails user = User
            .withUsername(user1.getName())
            .password(user1.getPassword())
            .build();

        return user;
    }
}
```

This will work if you are using Spring Data JPA in your project and you have extended `JpaRepository` or `CrudRepository` with `UserRepository` and you have `findByEmail` method in `UserRepository`.

If you want more information how to use Spring Data JPA and how to perform login using database values comment on this.